# Npm Install doesnt work on my other project

Tags: node.js, angular, windows, npm, npm-install

Npm Install doesnt work on my other project

Windows 10,
NPM - 6.14.4,
Node-gyp - v7.1.0,
Angular CLI: 9.1.7,
Node: 12.17.0,
OS: win32 x64

I am trying to run npm install in my windows.

This is the error below

```
C:\Users\SSD\Desktop\PATH_TO_MY_PROJECT>npm i core-js@3.4.2
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

> core-js@3.6.4 postinstall C:\Users\SSD\Desktop\PATH_TO_MY_PROJECT\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@7.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^10.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@7.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^10.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@7.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/forms@^10.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@7.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/localize@^10.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@10.0.7 requires a peer of @angular/compiler-cli@>=10.0.0-next.0 < 11 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@10.0.7 requires a peer of typescript@>=3.9 < 3.10 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\;C:\Users\SSD\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts;
npm ERR! file C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\;C:\Users\SSD\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts;
npm ERR! path C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\;C:\Users\SSD\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts;
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! core-js@3.6.4 postinstall: `node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"`
npm ERR! spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\;C:\Users\SSD\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts; ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the core-js@3.6.4 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\SSD\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-09-08T08_16_18_627Z-debug.log
```

Also here is my Error log files:

```
2167 warn notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
2168 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid OS:    darwin
2168 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid Arch:  any
2168 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual OS:   win32
2168 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual Arch: x64
2169 verbose stack Error: core-js@3.6.4 postinstall: `node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"`
2169 verbose stack spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\;C:\Users\SSD\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts; ENOENT
2169 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
2169 verbose stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
2169 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
2170 verbose pkgid core-js@3.6.4
2171 verbose cwd C:\Users\SSD\Desktop\PATH_TO_MY_PROJECT
2172 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
2173 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--scripts-prepend-node-path=auto"
2174 verbose node v12.17.0
2175 verbose npm  v6.14.4
2176 error code ELIFECYCLE
2177 error syscall spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\;C:\Users\SSD\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts;
2178 error file C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\;C:\Users\SSD\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts;
2179 error path C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\;C:\Users\SSD\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts;
2180 error errno ENOENT
2181 error core-js@3.6.4 postinstall: `node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"`
2181 error spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\;C:\Users\SSD\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts; ENOENT
2182 error Failed at the core-js@3.6.4 postinstall script.
2182 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2183 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

anyone pls help.

Comment: Have you try to delete the node_modules directory before starting npm install?

Comment: @CirrusMinor not yet. ill try it now

Comment: @CirrusMinor still the same error, pls help T_T


npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! core-js@3.6.4 postinstall: `node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"`

Comment: Have you figured this out? I have the same issue

Comment: @CodeMan03 have you tried this npm install -g npm@latest?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, could you try npm installing angular first and then try it again?

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear cache of npm & Also make your sure you have good internet connection
`npm cache clean --force`